# Getting random record from database with group by

Tags: php, mysql, random, group-by

Hello i have a question on picking random entries from a database. I have 4 tables, products, bids and autobids, and users.

```
Products
-------  
id 20,21,22,23,24(prime_key)
price...........
etc...........

users  
-------
id(prim_key)  
name user1,user2,user3  
etc  

bids  
-------
product_id  
user_id  
created  

autobids  
--------
user_id   
product_id
```

Now a multiple users can have an autobid on an product. So for the next bidder I want to select a random user from the autobid table

example of the query in language:

for each product in the autobid table I want a random user, which is not the last bidder.

On product 20 has user1,user2,user3 an autobidding.
On product 21 has user1,user2,user3 an autobidding

Then I want a resultset that looks for example like this

20 – user2
21 – user3

Just a random user. I tried miximg the GOUP BY (product_id) and making it RAND(), but I just can't get the right values from it. Now I am getting a random user, but all the values that go with it don't match.

Can someone please help me construct this query, I am using php and mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the solution is concerned with identifying the latest bid for each product:  these eventually wind up in temporary table "latest_bid".

Then, we assign randon rank values to each autobid for each product - excluding the latest bid for each product.  We then choose the highest rank value for each product, and then output the user_id and product_id of the autobids with those highest rank values.

```
create temporary table lastbids (product_id int not null, 
                                 created datetime not null, 
                                 primary key( product_id, created ) );

insert into lastbids 
select product_id, max(created)
from bids
group by product_id;

create temporary table latest_bid ( user_id int not null, 
                                    product_id int not null, 
                                    primary key( user_id, product_id) );

insert into latest_bid
select product_id, user_id 
from bids b
join lastbids lb on lb.product_id = b.product_id and lb.created = b.created;

create temporary table rank ( user_id int not null, 
                              product_id int not null, 
                              rank float not null, 
                              primary key( product_id, rank ));

# "ignore" duplicates - it should not matter
# left join on latest_bid to exclude latest_bid for each product

insert ignore into rank 
select user_id, product_id, rand() 
from autobids a
left join latest_bid lb on a.user_id = lb.user_id and a.product_id = lb.product_id 
where lb.user_id is null;

create temporary table choice 
as select product_id,max(rank) choice 
   from rank group by product_id;

select user_id, res.product_id from rank res
join choice on res.product_id = choice.product_id and res.rank = choice.choice;
```

Comment: Wow this looks like a very good solution to the problem. This most certainly get the result that i am looking for. I have questions about the performance tho. This query has to run every second in my system, as there could be a new auto bidding to be fired every second. Will it not be faster to get all the auto biddings into php, and then just with a loop filter out the unwanted. Creating a temporary table seems to be a bit slow to me, and i think functions as rand() and max() are too. I can be mistaken. I do have to say i am using inooDB tables.

Comment: The database approach could be improved by tracking the user_id and product_id of the latest bids for each product in a "latest_bid" table. A good way to maintain that table would be to add a trigger on the bids table so that every time a new bid is added, the latest_bid table is updated.  You could also cache the state of the bidding in a similar way - so the current bidder for a product is only recalculated when a new bid for that product arrives.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LIMIT statement in conjunction with server-side PREPARE.

Here is an example that selects a random row from the table mysql.help_category:

```
select @choice:= (rand() * count(*)) from mysql.help_category;
prepare rand_msg from 'select * from mysql.help_category limit ?,1';
execute rand_msg using @choice;
deallocate prepare rand_msg;
```

This will need refining to prevent @choice becoming zero, but the general idea works.

Alternatively, your application can construct the count itself by running the first select, and constructing the second select with a hard-coded limit value:

```
select count(*) from mysql.help_category;
# application then calculates limit value and constructs the select statement:   
select * from mysql.help_category limit 5,1;
```

Comment: Wow, I don't understand this answer at all, I am still kind of a beginner. What is the table mysql.help_category? And is this used in a loop?

Comment: mysql.help_category is a table that most installations will have that I used as an example.  Substitute your table for that. I will clarify the answer.  Whether this is used in a loop depends on what your application wants to do.

Comment: "depends on what my application wants to do"? My application wants to do what is asked in the question, that is get a random item per group from the autobids table. Is there a mothod of getting the whole as a result set, i don't want to loop trough the DB.And are functions like rand() and count() not a bad idea for the database. I  think getting the whole set from mysql and looping trough it with php is the same as this option performance wise.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood.  You would indeed need to repeat the process for each product.  I have added a new answer that would provide the solution for all products in the autobids table in one go.